# Kotlin: Iterable<T> from Sequence<T>

Tags: kotlin, iterator, java-stream, iterable, method-reference

In Kotlin, how can I get an `Iterable<T>` from a `Sequence<T>` or from a `Stream<T>`?

In Java, I can get `Iterable<T>`s via the following methods, but the equivalent Kotlin code doesn't work:

```
final Stream<T> s = /*get Stream*/;
final Iterable<T> i1 = s::iterator;
final Iterable<T> i2 = () -> s.iterator();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Kotlin has first-class function types, just providing a lambda or a method reference is not enough to coerce the expression into some Java interface. However, there is a concise syntax to implement a single-abstract-method interface:

```
val s: Stream<T> = /* get a stream */
val i = Iterable { s.iterator() }
```

Comment: Wait, why doesn't SAM conversion apply to `val i: Iterable<Int> = { s.iterator() }`?

Comment: Could it be because `Iterable` isn't annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`?

Comment: Why should that matter? In Java, any single-method interface is a functional interface whether it's annotated or not. Is the rule regarding the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation different in Kotlin?

Comment: @klitos It shouldn't, but here's the fact before you that Kotlin doesn't accept `Iterable` as a target for SAM conversion. I'm offering a reasonable interpretation of the behavior, even if it could be considered a bug.